# Error in insert with double quote in mariadb

Tags: java, mysql, apache-spark, mariadb

I am using Mariadb and trying to execute a simple insert query :

```
INSERT INTO admin ("ADMIN_CODE", "DEPT_CODE", "ID") VALUES ("xxx", "yyy", 1);
```

While executing the above query , I am getting the error as :

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '"ADMIN_CODE"...
```

The Mariadb version which I am using is :

```
10.3.31-MariaDB
```

I am trying to write the insert query from spark also then also I am getting the same error which I mentioned .

I tried enabling and disabling the `ANSI_QUOTES` sql modes , then also it is not working . Could anyone help with it ?

Comment: Use double-quotes only for JSON paths/values. In your query: use backticks (or none) for columns names, use single quotes for string-type values. Do not set `ANSI_QUOTES` (this makes no sense, you fix one error source but create another one).

Answer (score 0):

Remove the double quotes around the column names, and use single quotes for the string literals:

```sql
INSERT INTO admin (ADMIN_CODE, DEPT_CODE, ID)
VALUES
    ('xxx', 'yyy', 1);
```

Actually on MySQL/MariaDB either double quotes or backticks should be legal for escaping a column name.  But in your case, you don't need escaping, so don't use double quotes.

Comment: How can I do that with Spark ?? I have integrated the write to Spark , how can I remove the quotes from column name from Spark ?

Comment: I don't know Spark unfortunately.  Maybe someone else can build off my answer.